# Ext: news list maxWidth, maxHeight

Tags: typo3

building a news-list you can set two items "media maxWidth" and "media maxHeight".
Both parameters do not work really?

Both values you won't find as inline-style in the frontend:

[image]

Comment: How does your template look? Do a debug otherwise on the settings to check the fields in the frontend

Comment: This is the part out of Item.html:

`code`
<f:if condition="{newsItem.falMedia}">
…
   <f:image image="{mediaElement}" … maxWidth="{settings.list.media.image.maxWidth}" …/>
`code`

I debugged the output and I could find the settings: settings.list.media.image.maxHeight
but I didn't find a parameter that showed the content of the fields from the backend.
I guess that those fields are only for the single and not for the list output (? The partial "FalMediaImage" is in the folder "Details": <f:render partial="Detail/FalMediaImage"…/>).